Регулярные выражения, составление логина, проверка на повтор символа
Как составить регулярное выражение, которое позволит ввести латинские цифры (строчные или заглавные), цифры (0-9), и/или знак нижнего подчёркивания _, но при условии, что _ в строке встречаться будет только 1 раз или не встречаться вовсе?
Мой пример: [A-Za-z0-9_?]{3,25}
К сожалению такой пример захватывает строку вне зависимости от того, сколько раз там "_" встречается. А нужно, чтобы если там было два и более раза - строка не захватывалась
Michelle_Onell - должно захватиться  
MichelleOnell - должно захватиться  
Michelle__Onell - не должно захватиться  
_Michelle - должно захватиться  
_Michelle_ - не должно захватиться  

и т.п.

попробуйте ^(?!.*__)[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,25}$

https://regex101.com/r/KYr8Bq/1 ^(?=.{3,25}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$

^(?=.{3,25}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ — помог!
^(?!.*__)[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,25}$ — не помог; защищает от двух идущих друг за другом символов __, но если они встречаются раздельно, то не поможет _Michelle_Onelle
К сожалению, я не до конца понимаю, как именно сработал метод от Alexey Ten, чтобы в дальнейшем не повторять ошибок

^(?!.*__)(?=[^_]*_?[^_]*$)[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,25}$ В этом выражении:
^(?!.__) - снова запрещаем двойное нижнее подчёркивание.
(?=[^_]?[^]*$) - проверка, что _ встречается не более одного раза (или не встречается вовсе).
[A-Za-z0-9_] - разрешённые символы.
{3,25} - длина строки от 3 до 25 символов.
$ - конец строки.

^(?!.*__)(?=[^_]*_?[^_]*$)[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,25}$ — тоже подходит!

Верные:

^(?=.{3,25}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ от Alexey Ten
^(?!.*__)(?=[^_]*_?[^_]*$)[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,25}$ от Dev18

В 2-ом выражении:
^(?!.*__) - снова запрещаем двойное нижнее подчёркивание.
(?=[^_]*_?[^_]*$) - проверка, что _ встречается не более одного раза (или не встречается вовсе).
[A-Za-z0-9_] - разрешённые символы.
{3,25} - длина строки от 3 до 25 символов.
$ - конец строки.
